# Convert Float Obj in Dataframe for CountVectorizer & bow_transformer

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, scikit-learn, nlp

I am trying to load a dataframe into into bag of words and CountVectorizer but I get TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable when going loading from mess equal a test sentence to mess equaling the dataframe I need to use.

the example corpus on [scikit learn docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer.html) and the course online both loaded from just list of sentences instead of data frame.

**I tried Removing integers**

[AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'lower' in TFIDF and CountVectorizer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53986123/attributeerror-int-object-has-no-attribute-lower-in-tfidf-and-countvectoriz)

**I get different error**

TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

```
mess1 = [item for item in mess if not isinstance(item, int)]
```

this is what works

```
mess = 'Sample message! Notice: it has punctuation.'
```

**this is the dataframe** 
i need to use instead.

```
mess.head()
```

```
    |  bios                                                   |  artistName
----+---------------------------------------------------------+-------------------
0   |  Chris Cosentino Biography Chris Cosentino gre...       |  Chris Cosentino
----+---------------------------------------------------------+-------------------
1   |  Magda Biography The DJ known as Magda was bor...       |  Magda
----+---------------------------------------------------------+-------------------
2   |  Jean-Michel Cousteau Biography Since first be...       |  jean michel cousteau
----+---------------------------------------------------------+-------------------
3   |  Kyle Busch Biography The American stock car r...       |  Kyle Busch
----+---------------------------------------------------------+-------------------
4   |  Naughty by Nature Biography Naughty by Nature...       |  Naughty by Nature
----+---------------------------------------------------------+-------------------
```

```
nopunc = [c for c in mess if c not in string.punctuation]

def text_process(mess):

   nopunc = [char for char in mess if char not in string.punctuation]

   nopunc = ''.join(nopunc)

   return [word for word in nopunc.split() if word.lower() not in stopwords.words('english')]
```

```
mess['bios'].head(5).apply(text_process)
```

**Output**

```
0    [Chris, Cosentino, Biography, Chris, Cosentino...
1    [Magda, Biography, DJ, known, Magda, born, rai...
2    [JeanMichel, Cousteau, Biography, Since, first...
3    [Kyle, Busch, Biography, American, stock, car,...
4    [Naughty, Nature, Biography, Naughty, Nature, ...
Name: bios, dtype: object
```

```
mess.dtypes
```

```
bios          object
artistName    object
dtype: object
```

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
```

then run either

```
bow_transformer = CountVectorizer(analyzer=text_process)
bow_transformer.fit(mess['bios'])
print(len(bow_transformer.vocabulary_))
```

or this

```
bow_transformer = CountVectorizer(analyzer=text_process).fit(mess['bios'])

print(len(bow_transformer.vocabulary))
```

I get the error

**TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable**

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-148-74d381110eec> in <module>
     1 bow_transformer = CountVectorizer(analyzer=text_process)
----> 2 bow_transformer.fit(mess['bios'])
     3 print(len(bow_transformer.vocabulary_))

~\anaconda3\envs\nlp_course\lib\site-packages\sklearn\feature_extraction\text.py in fit(self, raw_documents, y)
   996         self
   997         """
--> 998         self.fit_transform(raw_documents)
   999         return self
  1000 

~\anaconda3\envs\nlp_course\lib\site-packages\sklearn\feature_extraction\text.py in fit_transform(self, raw_documents, y)
  1030 
  1031         vocabulary, X = self._count_vocab(raw_documents,
-> 1032                                           self.fixed_vocabulary_)
  1033 
  1034         if self.binary:

~\anaconda3\envs\nlp_course\lib\site-packages\sklearn\feature_extraction\text.py in _count_vocab(self, raw_documents, fixed_vocab)
   940         for doc in raw_documents:
   941             feature_counter = {}
--> 942             for feature in analyze(doc):
   943                 try:
   944                     feature_idx = vocabulary[feature]

<ipython-input-134-ad1781692b41> in text_process(mess)
     1 def text_process(mess):
     2 
----> 3     nopunc = [char for char in mess if char not in string.punctuation]
     4 
     5     nopunc = ''.join(nopunc)

TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable
```

Comment: Any missing values in the original frame?

Comment: I thought there was none but there where tons of fully empty. I will add information above.

Comment: I dropped the missing values but now I get TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Comment: Thanks Ben, one step closer to getting being able to play around with dataframe text. I should probably edit or create a new question as that is now a different question. Once I get it working will save a jupyter notebook for it.

Answer (score 0):

**Based Ben Reiniger Comment**

I looked for the missing values in the dataframe. Even though it was complete there was thousands of fully blank ones added.

I counted nan

```
count_nan = len(mess) - mess.count()
count_nan
```

```
bios          9682
artistName    9768
dtype: int64
```

**I ran dropna to remove them**

```
mess.dropna(inplace=True)
```

**output is now**

```
bios          0
artistName    0
dtype: int64
```

Error received when nan successfully dropped

Now I try to run bow_transformer = CountVectorizer(analyzer=text_process)

**that fixed my original TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable**

**however i get a new error but I am one step closer**.

```
bow_transformer = CountVectorizer(analyzer=text_process)

bow_transformer.fit(mess['bios'])

print(len(bow_transformer.vocabulary_))

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-62-74d381110eec> in <module>
     1 bow_transformer = CountVectorizer(analyzer=text_process)
----> 2 bow_transformer.fit(mess['bios'])
     3 print(len(bow_transformer.vocabulary_))

TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```